# Order By Advanced Custom Fields Subfield Date

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Sorry if this is redundant. I searched through everything a ton but can’t seem to figure it out.

I’ve got a group that has a start and end date. I’d like to order by the start date. The group’s name is showit_event_dates and the start date is start_event.

I’ve tried the way that ACF uses:

```
$args = array (
      'post_type'       => 'showit_events',
      'posts_per_page'  => $num_posts,
      'orderby'         => 'meta_value',
      'meta_key'        => 'start_event',
      'order'           => 'DESC'
    );
```

And by also using the meta_query instead of meta_key:

```
$args = array (
      'post_type'       => 'showit_events',
      'posts_per_page'  => $num_posts,
      'orderby'         => 'meta_value',
      'meta_query'     => array(
            array(
                'key'       => 'start_event',
                'value'     => date('F j'),
                'type'      => 'DATE',
                'compare'   => '=',
            )
        ),
      'order'           => 'DESC'
    );
```

Neither renders anything. I’m guessing because the dates in the group are treated as arrays???

Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay...thanks to a friend who sent me this link:
https://stuartfarish.com/advanced-custom-fields-sort-by-field-group-sub-field/

All you have to do is add the field name of the group to the beginning of the subfield. The name of my group is showit_event_dates. So, the code should look something like this:

```
$args = array (
      'post_type'       => 'showit_events',
      'posts_per_page'  => $num_posts,
      'orderby'         => 'meta_value',
      'meta_key'        => 'showit_event_dates_start_event',
      'order'           => 'DESC'
    );
```

Hope that helps someone

Comment: Was searching very long for this method. ACF should put this in their documentation in my opinion.